# Is there a JSF render tree preprocessor that collects the entity graph used by a facelet page?

Tags: jpa, jsf-2, lazy-loading

I've recently decided to do away with lazy loading in the view layer and fetch everything up front, since performance was just not acceptable for complicated views with >100 queries per page (to be clear, I'm *not* trying to fetch the full entity graph or avoid lazy loading altogether).

Now I'm looking for ways to ease the burden of maintaining such up front loading. And I have this idea that if I had the JSF render tree, including all EL expressions, I could traverse and collect all (or most of the) type information, constructing a fetch graph/forest that I could pass to a page initialization method.

Of course there are some constraints: I may collect too much information since I can't decide if an area is to be rendered before evaluating the corresponding expression. And it may not be feasible to parse EL expressions that aren't simple property traversals (eg include arithmetic or method calls). For this question, I'd like to ignore this.

Since writing such a thing is surely no small undertaking, I'd like to ask first: is there something like this already? If no, do you think it's feasible?

My environment would be JSF2.2 on a Wildfly-8 app server.